# Oracle Query from 3 tables

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am having problem when querying data from 3 tables `(FABRICATION, FABRICATION_QC, AND WEIGHT)` and using their values in the PHP. My query is like this:

```
select fabrication.*,master_drawing.weight,
                (select fabrication_qc.marking_qc from fabrication_qc where fabrication_qc.head_mark=fabrication.head_mark) MARKING_QC,
                (select fabrication_qc.marking_qc_date from fabrication_qc where fabrication_qc.head_mark=fabrication.head_mark) MARKING_QC_DATE,
                (select fabrication_qc.marking_qc_sign from fabrication_qc where fabrication_qc.head_mark=fabrication.head_mark) MARKING_QC_SIGN
                from fabrication,fabrication_qc,master_drawing
                where fabrication.head_mark = master_drawing.head_mark";
```

and when I do this in the PHP to get that data into a table,

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($fabParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) 
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>';

            var_dump($row['MARKING_QC']);
```

`PROJECT_NAME`, `HEAD_MARK`, and `ID` work fine. Only the dumped `MARKING_QC` shows `NULL` in the output.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is the query you really want:

```
select f.*, md.weight,
       (select fqc.marking_qc from fabrication_qc fqc where fqc.head_mark = f.head_mark) as MARKING_QC,
       (select fqc.marking_qc_date from fabrication_qc fqc where fqc.head_mark = f.head_mark) as MARKING_QC_DATE,
       (select fqc.marking_qc_sign from fabrication_qc fqc where fqc.head_mark = f.head_mark) as MARKING_QC_SIGN
from fabrication f join
     master_drawing md
     on f.head_mark = md.head_mark;
```

This removes the reference `fabrication_qc` in the outer `from` clause.  That simply causes an unnecessary cartesian product.  I also introduced table aliases to make the query more readable.  And, put in proper explicit join syntax rather than the implicit joins.

You can further simplify this to:

```
select f.*, md.weight,
       fqc.marking_qc, fqc.marking_qc_date, fqc.marking_qc_sign
from fabrication f join
     master_drawing md
     on f.head_mark = md.head_mark left outer join
     fabrication_qc fqc
     on fqc.head_mark = f.head_mark
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query like this:

```
select 
  f.project_name,
  f.head_mark,
  f.id,
  m.weight,
  qc.marking_qc, 
  qc.marking_qc_date,
  qc.marking_qc_sign 
from fabrication as f 
join master_drawing as m
  on  f.head_mark = m.head_mark
left outer join fabrication_qc as qc      
  on  f.head_mark = qc.head_mark

--  where (no criteria given)
;
```

Try running the query from a query execution tool outside of your code, to confirm the results.